# Elements are not showing properly using rowspan and colspan in mat-grid-list

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am new in Angular. I am trying to create one form in which i am not able to get the expected output. 
I am getting all toggles in one line. 
I tried many things but getting output like this: 
[image]

and my expected output i drawn on page:

[image]

I tried this:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="100px">
                <mat-grid-tile rowspan="2" class="mr-1">
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
                        <mat-label style="margin-right: 20px">Is Active?</mat-label>
                        <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="isActive"></mat-slide-toggle>
                    </div>
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
                        <mat-label style="margin-right: 20px">Is Supplier?</mat-label>
                        <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="isSupplier"></mat-slide-toggle>
                    </div>
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
                        <mat-label style="margin-right: 20px">Is Customer?</mat-label>
                        <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="isCustomer"></mat-slide-toggle>
                    </div>
                    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
                        <mat-label style="margin-right: 20px">Is Cashbook A/C?</mat-label>
                        <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="isCashbook"></mat-slide-toggle>
                    </div>
                </mat-grid-tile>
                <mat-grid-tile class="ml-1">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex>
                        <mat-label>Country</mat-label>
                        <input name="country" formControlName="country" matInput required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </mat-grid-tile>        
            </mat-grid-list>
            <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="100px">

                <mat-grid-tile class="ml-1">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex>
                        <mat-label>Phone</mat-label>
                        <input name="phone" formControlName="phone" matInput required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </mat-grid-tile>        
            </mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task with a nested `row/col` layout.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
   <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="50">
      <div>Where Height 100%</div>
   </div>
   <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="50">
     <div>Where Height 50%</div>
     <div>Where Height 50%</div>
   </div>
</div>
```